Problems in facet_grid and geom_signif interactions
I am currently trying to display the significance levels of a t-test in a plot with facets based on two categorical variables. My data consists of species belonging to specific complexes, with each species containing individuals of both genders. Because I want to display only the species belonging to each complex, I used the argument scales = "free_y" in my facet_grid. However, with this argument, the following error appeared:
Computation failed instat_signif()Caused by error inif (scales$x$map(comp[1]) == data$group[1] | manual) ...: ! missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed 

I read about the interaction between the facet_grid/facet_wrap functions and the ggsignif vignette, but I would like to avoid setting it manually, as my dataset consists of more than 36 species in 11 complexes. Is there any elegant way to achieve this?
I prepared an example code with the iris dataset that leads to the same error:
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggsignif)

data(iris)

sp_vector <- function() {
  species <- paste("sp", 1:6)
  rep(species, each = 25)
}

sp <- sp_vector()

iris$Species <- sp

complex_vector <- function() {
  species <- paste("comp", 1:3)
  rep(species, each = 50)
}

comp <- complex_vector()
iris$Complex <- comp

iris$Gender <- sample(c("M", "F"), size = 150, replace = T)

ggboxplot(iris, y = "Sepal.Length", x = "Species", fill = "Gender", width = 0.15, orientation = "horizontal") +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("sp1", "sp2")), 
              map_signif_level = TRUE, test = t.test) +
  theme_grey() +
  facet_grid(Complex~Gender, scales = "free_y") +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        strip.background.y = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y = element_blank())

